# How to make simultaneous ajax request to get JSON content from different URL's

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jquery

I need to make 10 simultaneous ajax request to get JSON content from different URL's.
Each request response is not dependent on each others. In this case how do I manage those requests?? 
I try using [AjaxManager plugin](http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/ajaxManager/)
but I can't configure it right to get JSON results.

Any help is very much appreciated! Please let me know if I can provide any more information. Thanks!

Comment: Do you need your handler to wait for all of them to return before doing anything?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simply use the '$.get();' method multiple times and it works simultaneously completely independent on each other. just as simple as that.
just like this...

```
$.get('myURL',function(data){
//do sth
});
$.get('myUrl2',function(data){
//do sth else
});
```

Comment: I try that, Browsers will block if they are 6-/+ requests at the same time (http://www.browserscope.org/)

Comment: But if it works for 6 requests then it still solves the problem of getting simultaneous ajax requests, Right? Just not an infinite number of them, which is not mentioned in the question.

Comment: The number of simultaneous requests is browser-dependent, so on IE7 (I think) this may be only 2

Answer (score 0):

I think the real question is, just how simultaneous do they need to be?  You can make them a bit less asynchronous by starting some of the requests on others' callbacks.

Comment: I want to make those requests on pageload

Comment: @Frank You can make the first few on page load, and the rest in their callbacks.  You wouldn't be getting the responses immediately anyway, so it shouldn't be much of a hit.